# Declare Typescript module when path is explicit

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, import, module

I have a project where I need to explicitly target the browser-compatible versions of a package so webpack can bundle it correctly.

```js
import { optimize, extendDefaultPlugins } from 'svgo/dist/svgo.browser'
```

Typically the import is:

```
import { optimize, extendDefaultPlugins } from 'svgo'
```

This works fine because there are types available at `@types/svgo`.

When I import from `'svgo/dist/svgo.browser'` I get the error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'svgo/dist/svgo.browser'`. How do I fix this error by rerouting the available types package at `@types/svgo` to my more explicit import statement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from the TypeScript side, but since you're using Webpack you can just cheat and [alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias) `'svgo'` to `'svgo/dist/svgo.browser'`:

```js
resolve: {
  alias: {
    svgo: require.resolve('svgo/dist/svgo.browser')
  }
}
```

Since TypeScript isn't aware of the Webpack alias it just sees you as importing the "normal" module and the `@types/svgo` enhancements get picked up by default, but Webpack pulls in the right code for your bundle.